# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yolov7.models'

Tags: python, machine-learning, path

I'm trying to move BotSORT on DockerContainer.

I wrote the code below on jupyter-notebook.Then,the Error written on title is occured.

[image]

Folder construct is below.

[image: 2]

Am I wrong about path? I'm new to Machine Learning.
Could anyone give me some advice? thanks.

Comment: Is `models` a submodule of `yolov7`?  Submodules are not imported automatically.  You may have to explicitly import it: `import yolov7.models`

Comment: @John Gordon  Thanks for your help.As you say, models is a submodule of yolov7. It is contained "BoTSORT>yolov7>models". I had tried explicitly import, but I could not resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have your yolov7 folder under another folder called BoTSORT. The way of fixing the import should be:

```
from BoTSORT.yolov7.models.experimental import attempt_load
```

Comment: Even after I turned your question into an answer, you might still want to add some explanation to improve the perveived helpfulness. Compare [answer].

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the folder that you want python to look into, to the path via:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, './yolov7')
```

And then python will be able to import models.